# F# - Compare LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero with a value passed on the class contructor

Tags: f#

Following the suggestions here, [F# GreaterThanZero passing int or decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71991828/f-greaterthanzero-passing-int-or-decimal), I'm trying to use `value > LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero` inside a class member function, but I can't find the way to use it.
Probably the issue is the fact the value is passed in the type contructor and not to the function.
Please, look at the the errors in the code comments.

```ml
type IValidationCheck =   
    abstract member Validate: unit -> Result<unit, string>

type NumberIsPositiveCheck (property:string, value) =
    interface IValidationCheck with
        member (*inline*) this.Validate () =  //# does not allow me to use "inline"
            if value > LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero then Ok()  //# fail to compile: the type IComparable does not have a get_Zero operator
            else Error $"{property} must be greater than zero"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler has no way to determine what the type of `value` is, and it needs that in order to resolve the right overload of `LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero`. The only thing the compiler knows about `value` is that you're comparing it using the `>` operator, and therefore it must implement `IComparable`. That's why `IComparable` appears in the error message.

One way to fix it is to explicitly specify the type of `value`:

```
type NumberIsPositiveCheck (property:string, value: int) =
  ...
```

But this will make the whole class non-generic, which is not what you want as far as I understand.

And here you're out of luck: you can't declare a generic class with one of type parameters being SRTP. This is because the underlying .NET virtual machine simply doesn't support such advanced type constraints. So there is no way to encode such class.

(well, to be completely precise, SRTPs on classes are in fact supported with some limitations, but definitely not in presence of interfaces)

---

But do not despair, not all is lost! If you look closely at your class, you'll notice that the result of `Validate()` is completely determined at the time of object construction. As soon as you call the constructor, the result of `Validate()` is already known right there.

So the simplest thing you can do is just pass in the boolean result instead of the value:

```
type NumberIsPositiveCheck (property:string, result) =
    interface IValidationCheck with
        member this.Validate () =
            if result then Ok()
            else Error $"{property} must be greater than zero"

let validator = NumberIsPositiveCheck("foo", 42 > 0)
```

Or you might event want to pass the whole `Result<_,_>`, cutting out the middle man completely.

---

But in order to cover all my bases, let's assume that for some unknown reason you do want to pass the value itself, not the boolean result.

If that's the case, you can also pass the generic zero along with the value itself, and then inside `Validate()` do the comparison:

```
type NumberIsPositiveCheck (property:string, value, zero) =
    interface IValidationCheck with
        member this.Validate () =
            if value > zero then Ok()
            else Error $"{property} must be greater than zero"

let validator = NumberIsPositiveCheck("foo", 42, 0)
```

Or, alternatively, you could pass a comparison function rather than specifically zero:

```
type NumberIsPositiveCheck (property:string, value, compare) =
    interface IValidationCheck with
        member this.Validate () =
            if compare value then Ok()
            else Error $"{property} must be greater than zero"

let validator = NumberIsPositiveCheck("foo", 42, fun x -> x > 0)
```

And from here the next step becomes obvious: why are you writing a class in the first place? Its only purpose seems to be implementing the interface, and that you can do without a class at all:

```
let inline numberIsPositiveCheck (property:string) value =
    { new IValidationCheck with
        member this.Validate () =
            if value > LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero then Ok()
            else Error $"{property} must be greater than zero"
    }

let validator = numberIsPositiveCheck "foo" 42
```

Boom! Now you don't have to pass the zero as a parameter, because now it's a function, not a class, so it can have SRTPs.

---

Moral of the story: fewer classes, more functions. Classes are useful much less frequently than functions are.